# Using SASS in React Native

Tags: react-native, sass

I'm trying to find a way to implement SASS in my react native project. All I found is this package [react-native-sass-transformer](https://github.com/kristerkari/react-native-sass-transformer), but it doesn't seem to work on my end. Tried looking for other way but all I see is approach in React instead. Does anyone know another way into implementing SASS in a react native cli project? Thank you!

Comment: There is possibility that you have missed some configurations. Have you done any configurational changes to the metro.config.js ?

Comment: Yes I did. As per the instructions, I added the [following](https://file.io/3WVe4JuijsUr) in addition to the old configs of my project.

Edit: I can't reference the sass file I created in the same folder of the file I wanted to use it in. It also doesn't show on intellisense.

Comment: Try this [tutorial](https://blog.logrocket.com/sass-react-native-guide/). it's works.

Comment: That is actually the tutorial that I followed.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you're trying to use react native sass transformer with .tsx (typescript implementation), if it's the case, you just need to :

```
//@ts-ignore
import styles from './app.scss';
```

And then it should work.
You can also use: https://github.com/kristerkari/react-native-typed-sass-transformer to handle types (I didn't tried yet, but I'll !)

Good luck!

Comment: Yes I do use typescript. I did this but the scss file still doesn't show on intellisense. Tried using it anyway since it doesn't highlight the `import styles from ./app.scss` as error but it throws a compile error saying that the file doesn't exist. Will try to use the package for ts transformer but if you have an idea on the first approach, kindly let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Expo and running it on the web? , if that's the case, the problem you're getting is caused because by default Expo uses webpack and not Metro, so it is required to change app.js

```
{
  "expo": {
    ...,
    "packagerOpts": {
      "config": "metro.config.js",
      "sourceExts": ["ts", "tsx", "scss"] /* Typescript and scss */
    },
    "web": {
      "bundler": "metro", /* Expo Web uses webpack by default */
      ...
    },
    ...
  }
```

more information [here](https://github.com/kristerkari/react-native-sass-transformer/issues/32)